# Adding padding to imageView within UITableViewCell?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, swift, imageview, padding

I have a UITableViewCell wherein I am adding the user's facebook profile picture, but rounded. Essentially, this:

```
self.imageView.image = _fbProfilePicture!
self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.imageView.frame.size.height/2
self.imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

However, this image is flush with the edges of the UITableViewCell. I want to add some breathing room between the image and the edge of the cell, but I haven't come across a simple way to do this. Can anyone suggest a solution, possibly something that doesn't require manipulating the prototype cell in the storyboard? Thanks!

Comment: You should add constraints to the controls in your prototype cell.

Comment: Can you add a picture of what it looks like?